# Blown head gasket 2016 Chevy Cruze lt 1.4l eco turbo

Tags: engine, oil, radiator, head-gasket, antifreeze

I have head gasket repair. However I can’t use it with antifreeze in my radiator. How would I got about flushing my radiator with antifreeze in my oil? Do I drain oil first and put new oil in and then empty my antifreeze? And use a flush? I’m teaching myself how to fix my car thru YouTube videos but none of them help me with my dilemma.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!